# Exclude a specific folder in All Users OU - Google Workspace

Tags: google-workspace

I just stated working with a company that uses google workspace. They have a group distribution list that sends email to all users container. However, within all users container, there is also a container for Terminated Employees. Is there a way to set up the distribution list so that it doesn't forward the emails to the Terminated Users Container?

thanks,
Glenn

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you have two straight forward options so users stop getting those emails:

- Remove terminated or suspended users from the group membership. Here you can check how to do it. https://support.google.com/a/answer/10284003

If for some reason you don't want to remove the user from that distribution list, you can disable the user from getting those group messages.

- go to groups.google.com and choose the group in question.
  Go to members, you will see all users in that group and under the "subscription" column choose "No email". That will stop the user from getting those group inbound messages.

For the second option you need to have the group "Owner" role otherwise you will have to login into the terminated user session to make these changes.